# ui-grid angularjs checkbox button not being resorted

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a checkbox column using ui-grid after I check one column and sort with another column for example age, the active column is not being resorted.

This is a plunkr of the problem

[http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3Fs3XiRBpqkzKdZlGXW?p=preview](http://%22http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3Fs3XiRBpqkzKdZlGXW?p=preview%22)

Comment: We (atleast I) cannot understand you...

Comment: please see the plnkr , what i am trying to say is when i check the active button of the first row for example and then i sort my grid with the age column the checked active button is always on the first row

Comment: Ya, I'm doing it right now

Comment: to see the problem do this 1.open plnkr  2.check the first row active checkbox 3.sort the grid using the age column 4.you will notice that checked active column is still on the first row even after sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your cell template. You are not binding the value isActive to the checkbox.

Change the checkbox column to this

```
{ 
name: 'isActive', 
displayName: 'Active', 
type: 'boolean',
cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.isActive">'
}
```

This plnkr works right.
http://plnkr.co/edit/PL7HvK1FY2ycuOrBbBTA?p=preview